# SaaS Multi Tenant Application Jumpstart

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant, saas

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC 5 web application that I sell to multiple customers. I would like to rewrite what I currently have into a Multi Tenant site that basically manages itself.

I am looking for something like ASP.NET Boilerplate but on steriods. I would like it to include complete tenant management; ie Create subscriptions, onboard customers, customer security, create users per customer, user security, bill/track payments, etc. I could then migrate my current application code into the tenant management application.

Is there anything like this out there?

Comment: This is very broad and doesn't involve a programming problem. Please be specific on your question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the right thing you are looking for, prmarily not MVC, but it could be helpfull....

http://yatendra.github.io/saasapp/

Comment: Thank-you! This was very useful and I had not seen this one, yet.